# Multiple Pano2VR canvas tags

Tags: canvas, webgl, preloader, preloading, panoramas

I'm building a web app that has multiple panoramas built with Pano2VR, which is basically a software that can spit out a textured WebGL cubic panoramas in a canvas tag.  I want to put about 11 of these on a single page so that when the user requests one, the browser doesn't have to load a separate page. I just have to unhide it and bring it to the front.

The problem is, when I put more than 9 of these panoramas (which are WebGL canvases) on a single page, some of the canvases go blank.  I'm guessing this is a memory issue.  This app is running locally, so all the assets are local not downloaded or anything.  I'm not doing any sort of pre-loading, so I'm wondering if that might fix it.  I've never worked with pre-loading or anything, so I'm not sure if it would even help.

Has anyone ever dealt with having multiple canvas tags or multiple WebGL canvas tags on a page and having some go blank? If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in the case of Pano2VR, you can load a separate panorama into the same div container.  That is, you can enter the container name as a parameter for a pano2vrPlayer class, then just run the readConfigUrl() function on a separate XML file, and it will create another canvas in the container.  That way, every time you request a panorama, it loads it as needed.  I haven't run into any issues with the app slowing down because the previously loaded panorama was still taking up memory, so the problem seems solved.  The app loads with no speed issues now.